# Access binary data of <audio> src

Tags: html, html5-audio

For some small hacking project I would like to load the raw data
of an MP3 into an ArrayBuffer.

```
<audio src="http://xyz.com/test.mp3">
```

I know that there are some basic functions exposed by an `<audio>` element but I was not able to find what I'm looking for. It is very likely that if there is such thing it is part of the Web Audio API and only works in Chrome by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access raw data of HTML5 `<audio>` element.

What you can do is

- Load data via AJAX
- Grab raw data from the result for your internal purposes
- Pass data forward to audio element (probably need to do data-uri here)

But for this kind on manipulation I recommend using Web Audio API instead of `<audio>`:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Firefox support should land in few iterations.

Comment: The problem with that is that the audio data is coming from a different origin. I thought that it might be possible to ship around that problem by using the `<audio>` tag. Thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: Fix your different origin to use CORS headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this level of access to the different origin. (Thats why I've been looking into other possible options like using the `<audio>` tag.)

Comment: Then you are working against Internet security model.... unless you set up a proxy server it is impossible to grab data. Otherwise you could steal data off any server with user cookie priviledges.

Comment: Any updates on this in these modern times or still not possible?

Comment: A lot of has changed in 10 years in the web development, so much better alternatives should be available.